# REST resource for managing static assets in Google App Engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-api

Is there REST API for managing static assets in a Google App Engine app/project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static assets are managed at application update (upload) time. There is no other API at present. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was looking for a quick way to add image files to the public_root after the application has been deployed. doesn't seem like there is a way to do that.

Comment: static files are also served via different infrastructure fyi. So changing them on the fly is not possible as Dave notes.